# remove whitespaces and blank spaces in next line

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I've the below piece of code.

```
<sup><a name="f31" href="#ftn.31" class="tr_ftn">
                                31</a></sup> the
```

here i want to replace the space between the closing tag and the number, the output should look like the below.

```
<sup><a name="f31" href="#ftn.31" class="tr_ftn">31</a></sup> the
```

the regex i'm using is

```
 class="tr_ftn">\n*
```

but it is taking the full next line.

please let me know how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: Try `\n *` instead of `\n*` in your regex.

Comment: See my updated answer for Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot how [different the visual studio 2010 expressions are](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can use:

```
class="tr_ftn"\>:Wh*:Cc*:Wh*
```

That will match class="tr_ftn">, followed by any number of spaces, then any number of the newlines,  and spaces.

If that is your match then you will want to replace with:

```
class="tr_ftn">
```

For Visual Studio 2012 you would use as the match:

```
class="tr_ftn">[\r\n\s]*
```